# Compute world position by walking N units along spline?

Tags: c#, unity, optimization, splines

My goal is to move ahead along a spline 'x' world units, unfortunately there is no way to map spline points to world points.

What I do is I iterate along the spline by a small alpha amount (say 0.001), get the new spline point vs the old one and add the difference to a total up until it equals or is slightly greater than the distance I wanted to move in world space.

This works fine but there is a huge bottleneck with the sqrt, basically to calculate the distance between two vector points you need to do a square root calculation.

I feel it should be possible to just get the squared value and just use that, unfortunately I can't get the code working, here is what I have:

Where `_distance` is the amount to move, Distance is the alpha value along the spline.

```
        float distanceMoved = 0;

        float oldDistance = Distance;

        while (distanceMoved < (_distance))
        {
            Vector3 before = Position;
            float oldAlpha = Alpha;
            float oldDist = Distance;
            Distance += _iteration;

            distanceMoved += (before - Position).magnitude;
        }
```

Notice the line with `(before - Position).magnitude`, the .magnitude property performs a square root.

I've tried changing it to .sqarMagnitude and say distanceMoved < distance * distance but it has accelerated the rate of movement forwards.

Any ideas what is going wrong or how I can get rid of the square rooting or do this differently entirely?

Comment: You know that `10 + 10 + 10 != Sqrt(10*10 + 10*10 + 10*10)` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem I'm having?

Comment: This just explains why your "optimization" does not work as expected.

Comment: You should fix your variable names. If `Distance` is the alpha value, why not call it `Alpha`? And… what is `Alpha`, then?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do a linear search!!! You should opt for a binary search in the first place. Secondly, you should have multiplied the desired distance by itself i.e. `desired_distance_to_move * desired_distance_to_move` than do a binary or (in case you care not of performance) a linear search for a point with a distance * distance > desired_distance^2 (and < [desired_distance^2 + 1]) if you are doing binary search).

How to do binary search in a situation like this:

`a` is the estimated step size.

`t` is the current position on the spline.

`distance_2()` is a function that returns the square distance without using root obviously

`spline()` gets you a position on the spline

```
old_pos = spline(t);
curr_dist_2 = distance_2(old_pos, spline(t + a));
step_size = a;

while (curr_dist_2 < desired_dist_2)
  {
    a += step_size;
    step_size *= 2;
    curr_dist_2 = distance_2(old_pos, spline(t + a));
  }


while (curr_dist_2 > desired_dist_2 + 1 || curr_dist_2 < desired_dist_2)
 {
   step_size /= 2;
   if (curr_dist_2 > desired_dist_2 + 1)
     {
       a -= step_size;
     }
   else
     {
       a += step_size;
     }
   curr_dist_2 = distance_2(old_pos, spline(t + a));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the curvature of your spline is small enough, there is a method that will speed up things while remaining accurate. The idea is the same as developed in my answer to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27056/how-to-achieve-uniform-speed-of-movement-on-a-bezier-curve/27138): if iterating by `alpha` makes you advance by `distance`, then iterating by `K * alpha` will make you advance by *approximately* `K * distance` as long as `K` is not too large.

Given your desired distance `_distance`, the function becomes as ridiculously short as this:

```
    float const d = 0.001;

    Vector3 oldPosition = Position;

    Distance += d;
    Distance += d * (_distance / (oldPosition - Position).magnitude - 1.0);
```

Now of course if `_distance` becomes too large, the approximation no longer works well. You can fix this by doing a small, reasonable number of iterations instead:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        Advance(_distance / 10.0);
```